# How to deal with calling data that is parsed into a hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, printing

So I parsed the following XML code using Perl and i'm trying to call the spectrum results but i'm having difficulty since it is a hash. I keep getting the error message reference found where even sized list expected.

```
<message>
  <cmd id="result_data">
    <result-file-header>
      <path>String</path>
      <duration>Float</duration>
      <spectra-count>Integer</spectra-count>
    </result-file-header>
    <scan-results count="Integer">
      <scan-result>
        <spectrum-index>Integer</spectrum-index>
        <time-stamp>Integer</time-stamp>
        <tic>Float</tic>
        <start-mass>Float</start-mass>
        <stop-mass>Float</stop-mass>
        <spectrum count="Integer">mass,abundance;mass1,abundance1;
          mass2,abundance2</spectrum>
      </scan-result>
      <scan-result>
        <spectrum-index>Integer</spectrum-index>
        <time-stamp>Integer</time-stamp>
        <tic>Float</tic>
        <start-mass>Float</start-mass>
        <stop-mass>Float</stop-mass>
        <spectrum count="Integer">mass3,abundance3;mass4,abundance4;
          mass5,abundance5</spectrum>
      </scan-result>
    </scan-results>
  </cmd>
</message>
```

Here is the Perl code i'm using:

```
my $file = "gapiparseddataexample1.txt";
unless(open FILE, '>'.$file) {
die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
}

use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $values= XMLin('samplegapi.xml', ForceArray => [ 'scan-result' ,'result-file-header']);
print Dumper($values);

my $results = $values->{'cmd'}->{'scan-results'}->{'scan-result'};
my $results1=$values->{'cmd'}->{'result-file-header'};

for my $data (@$results) {
 print FILE "Spectrum Index",":",$data->{"spectrum-index"},"\n";
 print FILE "Total Ion Count",":",$data->{tic},"\n";
 %spectrum=$data->{spectrum};

print FILE "Spectrum",":",%spectrum, "\n";
    for my $data1 (@$results1) {
        print FILE "Duration",":",$data1->{duration},"\n";
 }
}
```

I want to be able to print out the spectrum value pairs.

Comment: Why do you have spaces between `result-file-` and `header` in the perl code?

Comment: upload error...its not actually in the perl code

Comment: Which line is the error on? `%spectrum=$data->{spectrum}`?

Comment: i tried putting single quotes around $data->{spectrum} and it says odd number of elements in hash assignment...

Comment: The problem is that spectrum isn't a hash, why are you trying to assign it to a hash variable?

Comment: when i have it print out like the other values it is says it is a hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 $spectrum=$data->{spectrum};

print FILE "Spectrum",":", $spectrum->{'content'}, "\n";
for my $data1 (@$results1) {
        print FILE "Duration",":",$data1->{duration},"\n";
}
```

Should give you this (which I assume is what you want):

```
Spectrum:mass,abundance;mass1,abundance1;
      mass2,abundance2
```

You'll want to remove the newline value from 'content' I imagine (so it doesn't split over two lines).

**Explanation for anyone that's curious**

The element contents have been shoved into "->content" because  element also has an attribute. In this case, one called "count":

```
<spectrum count="Integer">mass3,abundance3;mass4,abundance4;
          mass5,abundance5</spectrum>
```

This sort of behaviour is common in other languages and other XML parsing libraries too (e.g. sometimes they shove it into an element with the key 0). Sometimes it happens even when elements don't have regular attributes but are of specific types.

If you were to var dump $data->{$spectrum} you'd see the structure (again that usually applies in other languages and with other XML parsing libraries too).